# Camera orientation issues on phonegap iPhone development

Tags: javascript, iphone, cordova, camera, orientation

I'm using phonegap in order to capture an image in my application.

My application is configured to work in landscape orientation mode, with the button on the right.

The thing is that I need to keep that orientation when taking a photo with the camera.

I'm using the 1.4.1 version of the phonegap library. I have tried passing "correctOrientation: true" as a cameraOption parameter when calling capturePhoto(), but it doesn't seem to work and the device continues taking and storing the images as the device accelerometer tells.

Any idea how to solve it?

Comment: check my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9902797/phone-gap-camera-orientation/10196279#10196279