# Phone Gap camera orientation

Tags: android, cordova

I have developed an app using Phone Gap version **0.9.3**...

When I open camera in my app ,it always opens in landscape mode and, on capture, the image is returned  in landscape format...

How can I change the mode of camera to portrait

```
navigator.camera.getPicture(onsuccess, fail, {quality: 45,destinationType : Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, sourceType: src},img_id);

function onsuccess(imageData) {
    localStorage.setItem("image_captured","Yes");
    $('#'+imgID).attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData);
    $("#"+imgID+"_IMG").attr('src', 'data:image/jpeg;base64,' + imageData);
}
```

In manifest i had mention:

```
<activity android:name="com.android.camera.Camera"
    android:screenOrientation="portrait">
</activity>
```

Please help me in this...

Comment: why dont u update it to atleast 1.0...

Comment: i had created an custom plugin for spinner.. this plugin is not working in the 1.0 or above.. so had fixed to 0.9.3 where my plugin is working fine..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9841742/selection-option-in-phonegap-not-working-proper .. this is an another issue in my app..

Comment: i think u'll have to find a way of making spinner work with 1.0 first. there have been loads of changes since 0.9.3
difficult o debug'

Comment: ya version is changed to 1.4.1 .. same problem with camera....

Answer (score 7, accepted):

photo orientation is not stored when returning an image in base64 format (all EXIF data is stripped).

You should use the accelerometer or screen orientation to "know" if the image was taken in portrait or landscape and then display it accordingly.

Answer (score 18):

Try this : correctOrientation: true

```
function getPhoto(source) {

    navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoURISuccess, onFail, { quality: 30, 
    destinationType: destinationType.FILE_URI,
    sourceType: source,
    correctOrientation: true });

}
```

Comment: correctOrientation is currently ignored on most devices (android included)

Comment: @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck I'm also facing the issue that a picture taken in portrait mode is returned in landscape mode when trying to display it in HTML right after the picture has been taken. How do you fix that? "correctOrientation" does not help and seems to be ignored (Emulator/Nexus and Galaxy S3), that's true...

Comment: @PerHornshøj-Schierbeck Thanks, I've also added a solution - for me the "correctOrientation" parameter works just fine now.

Answer (score 6):

The "correctOrientation" parameter works fine for me - but only if you're also using the "targetWidth" and "targetHeight" parameters (e.g. set them to "800"). It seems that some devices may not have enough memory to rotate a full resolution picture.

Update:
Here's a nice article with useful information about memory, scaling and EXIF issues with the Phonegap Camera code:
http://simonmacdonald.blogspot.ca/2012/07/change-to-camera-code-in-phonegap-190.html

Comment: Nice find. It still doesn't always work for me setting the sizes though. Could be version related? On 4.3 here...

Comment: Thanks, I'm using appgyver and had same problem on Android 4.4, your solution worked (I'm loading the image as data url).

Comment: perfect. correctOrientation parameter works for me along with targetWidth and targetHeight. thanks so much

Answer (score 0):

I've solved my problem my saving as file url instead. The file will be placed in a temporally folder along with correct EXIF data. There might be some devices where you have to manually delete the files when closing the application though.

When referencing the file url instead of the data, the img seem to get displayed correctly.